# Как перенести скрипт с debian на windows 7?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Всем добра.Переношу скрипт который писал на прекрасном любимом дебиан,в ненавистную виндовс 7.
Проблемы путей я так понял решаются двойным слэшем,то есть было / ,стало для винды так `\\`.
Это ладно,теперь уже часа 2 бьюсь с ошибкой

```
    File "C:\Python3.5\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 4484: character maps to <undefined>
```

Не могу победить,уже все перепроверил везде UTF-8.Но ошибка надоедливо ест мозг.Помогите плиз,спасибо!
p.s. ошибка вылазит при установке аддонов через selenium в firefox.Путь до аддонов

```
C:\no_restart
```

в скрипте

```
directory = 'C:\\no_restart\\'
files = os.listdir(directory)
addon = directory + str(random.choice(files))
```

Все имена файлов на английском

Полный лог ошибки

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 162.1967.10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1580, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 964, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/root/PycharmProjects/untitled/script.py", line 161, in <module>
    regger()
  File "C:/Users/root/PycharmProjects/untitled/script.py", line 56, in regger
    fp.add_extension(addon)
  File "C:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 92, in add_extension
    self._install_extension(extension)
  File "C:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 271, in _install_extension
    addon_details = self._addon_details(addon)
  File "C:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 344, in _addon_details
    manifest = f.read()
  File "C:\Python3.5\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 4484: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: *то есть было / ,стало для винды так \\* -- а разве винда не понимает прямые слэши?

Comment: Нет,ругалась на них

Comment: Пример кода в вопросе не соответствует приведённому traceback. Более информативно привести текст ошибки и какое действие  к ней привело в заголовке. Попытайтесь создать с нуля минимальный пример, который приводит к той же ошибке. Опишите что вы ожидаете код сделать и что вместо этого происходит по шагам (если запускаете в PyCharm это следует упомянуть и проверить что происходит, если запустить в Windows консоле). Ошибка похоже из-за  неверной кодировки при чтении файла, передайте явно правильную кодировку вместо используемой по умолчанию кодировки из локали(на Windows это cp1251, Debian—utf-8)